# Rotate clip-path from bottom right side to the bottom left side

Tags: css, clip-path

I have a button on css:

```css
button {
  background: #FB5D5D;
  width: 350px;
  height: 54px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  transition: clip-path 3s ease, transform 3s ease, -webkit-clip-path 3s ease;
}

button:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #D92121 0%, #FF6464 100%);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: clip-path .3s ease;
  clip-path: polygon(200% 0, 0 200%, 0 0);
}

button:hover:after {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 0, 0 0);
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="w-full font-bold">Send</button>
```

How I can start animation from bottom left side, but not right? I need when user hover on button, animation should start from left and go to from light bg to dark (light сolor should be on the whole button as it is now). Help please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by just using `transfomr: rotateY(0.5turn);` to rotate that `90deg` and make that animation from `right`.

#### EDIT

change the angle of the background-gradient `-270deg` to move the dark side to right.

```css
button {
  background: #FB5D5D;
  width: 350px;
  height: 54px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  transition: clip-path 3s ease, transform 3s ease, -webkit-clip-path 3s ease;
}

button:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(-270deg, #D92121 0%, #FF6464 100%);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: clip-path .3s ease;
  clip-path: polygon(200% 0, 0 200%, 0 0);
  transform: rotateY(0.5turn);
}

button:hover:after {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 0, 0 0);
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="w-full font-bold">Send</button>
```

Comment: dark side of gradient must be on right, but not left :) I need rotate only clip-path animation

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform: scaleX(-1)` to flip the `::after` selector. You can change the angle of gradient to `90deg` to make the dark side go right.

```css
button {
  background: #FB5D5D;
  width: 350px;
  height: 54px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  transition: clip-path 3s ease, transform 3s ease, -webkit-clip-path 3s ease;
}

button:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #D92121 0%, #FF6464 100%);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: clip-path .3s ease;
  clip-path: polygon(200% 0, 0 200%, 0 0);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

button:hover:after {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 0, 0 0);
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="w-full font-bold">Send</button>
```

Comment: dark side of gradient must be on right, but not left :)